# How to grep single quotes grep " ' "?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, grep

I'm smashing myself trying to grep single quotes, not a word within single quotes `'word'`,   `but " ' ' "`

```
cat file;

.




$servers->setValue(‘server’,’base’,array(‘dc=aulendil,dc=com’))



.
```

and I want to have output with following result:

```
grep " ' " file;

.

content........'.....'.....content.......'.....'..........'.....................'.......content

.

EOP
```

Comment: are you trying to grep for just a single quote?  or a space followed by a single-quote followed by another space?   your example greps for the latter.  try `grep "'" file` (i.e. without the spaces).  btw you do not need `cat` to grep a file.

Comment: Could you please edit your question using the toolbar available (four space indent for code/verbatim text). It's difficult to make out what you data is and what you expect to get.  It is furthermore difficult to see what you want to do (grep for a single quote, or for a pair of consecutive single quotes, or for a single quoted word).  Are the dots part of the expected output of of your input?

Comment: Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I'm trying to grep single quotes only, like grep " ' " filename. I just decided it would make sense for previosly runned cat comment followed by grep'ing

Comment: In what way does `grep "'"` not do this?  Please [edit] you question with the _expected outcome_ and also add what you actually get when you try it.

Comment: I already asked my question pretty straightforward Kusalananda. I need to grep single quotes only, I have no intention to grep anything else besides single quotes

Comment: So, what happens when you grep for a single quote?  As far as your question goes, you seem to want to _change_ most of the output to dots and to the string `contents`. Please update it to show actual data.

Comment: Those are not ordinary single quotes though.  See the difference between `’` and `'`.

Comment: There is no output, it's not working. I've tried grep " ' " filename and it doesn't grep single quotes

Comment: I see your point about unordinary quotes, I've might edit with single quotes on my own shell and see it works

Comment: If the text has been pasted into a word processor or similar, the quotes may have changed to "smart quotes".  You likely do not want to use smart quotes in a piece of Perl code (or whatever that is).

Comment: This question is a mess. I tried to edit the question for you, to tidy it. But the source code for the question is also a mess. Please fix it, please respond to comments by amending question, not it comments.

Answer (score 2):

An ordinary single quote can be grepped for using `grep "'"`.

This text, however, [has been pasted into Microsoft Word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532425/how-to-grep-single-quotes-grep#comment985526_532425).  This word processor changes quotes into "smart quotes" (or "typographical quotes").  A set of smart single quotes (`‘...’`) are different from a set of ordinary straight single quotes (`'...'`) and would not be found by `grep` if searching for an ordinary single quote.  Note also that the opening and closing single quote is different from each other when using smart single quotes.

Simply don't use Microsoft Word as an intermediate staging area for code, as it changes things unexpectedly.  Code copied from Microsoft Word would probably not work as expected.

Comment: +1. in short, use a text editor, not a word processor.

Comment: or (if you're masochistic) use a character class containing different kinds of single-quotes.   e.g. `grep "[‘'’]" filename`.   the 3 different single-quotes were copy-pasted from the OP's example above.  They are not the only possible single-quote characters that might be used by different word-processors with different fonts, unicode settings, etc.